# Generate a Media entity from a remote URL?

Tags: media, 9

I want to create embeddeable "media" similar to how embedding YouTube or Vimeo videos work. When a URL is pasted in, I want to store this as a media entity (its own type) and then render it out with an oEmbed formatter (it has an iframe tag and attached JS library). This way, adding them for editors is easy and later re-usable for embedding as media objects. Where do I look in the Media system to support this? (note - its not images or video)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it supports [oEmbed](https://oembed.com/providers.json) you can use `OEmbed` Source plugin similar to below.

https://git.drupalcode.org/sandbox/Bhanu951-3225164/-/blob/1.x/src/Plugin/media/Source/TikTok.php

If it doesn't support oEmbed you can create your own media source plugin extending `MediaSourceBase` class similar to below.

https://git.drupalcode.org/project/media_entity_slideshow/-/blob/8.x-2.x/src/Plugin/media/Source/Slideshow.php

Edit 1 :

In order to store it as own media type you need to extended `oEmbed` class and define `providers` [key](https://git.drupalcode.org/sandbox/Bhanu951-3225164/-/blob/1.x/src/Plugin/media/Source/TikTok.php#L14) to provide oEmbed source. All the additional metadata will be handled by `oEmbed` class.

You can alter the source data by using `hook_media_source_info_alter` refer
https://git.drupalcode.org/sandbox/Bhanu951-3225164/-/blob/1.x/media_entity_tiktok.module#L11

Comment: Huh, no code within it? How can I store it as its own media type? The service does support OEmbed.