# can't embed Rumble videos in oEmbed providers module

Tags: media

I've got oEmbed providers installed on two sites and recently wanted to add rumble to the list of providers. I've created a new provider bucket and included rumble but if I try and add a rumble URL or embed URL it gives me an:

"InvalidArgumentException: Unknown provider 'Rumble.com' in Drupal\oembed_providers\OEmbed\ProviderRepositoryDecorator->get() (line 217 of modules/contrib/oembed_providers/src/OEmbed/ProviderRepositoryDecorator.php)".

I've come to understand that the provider name has to be exact. Within the OEMBED Providers json file the rumble info looks like this:

```
    {
     "provider_name": "Rumble",
     "provider_url": "https://rumble.com/",
     "endpoints": [
       {
         "url": "https://rumble.com/api/Media/oembed.{format}",
         "discovery": true
      }
    ]
  },
```

notice the provider_name is "Rumble".

If I go to iframely.com and paste in a rumble URL I will see, under the oEmbed tab, that the provider name is Rumble.com. I tried to create a custom provider called Rumble.com but the machine name reverts to rumble_com so it doesn't work.

I've looked for the answer to this all over the internet and I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/311478

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate a Media entity from a remote URL?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/311470/generate-a-media-entity-from-a-remote-url)

Comment: not necessarily. the oEmbed Providers module includes Rumble but when checked it doesn't work. i don't really want to create another module to perform a function that oEmbed providers is capable of

Comment: A keyword search of “rumble” in the module’s issue turned up this full solution from the maintainer as the first result: https://www.drupal.org/project/oembed_providers/issues/3253757#comment-14392459

Comment: Thank you @cilefen, I've tried that too but didn't work on either of my sites

Comment: The module maintainer wrote that comment so you may wait here indefinitely for a better answer.